# XAMPP / PHP - "MongoDB\Driver\Manager" not found

Tags: php, xampp

I'm trying to run PHP on **MacOS** with MongoDB.
MongoDB runs in a Docker Container.

Calling localhost in Browser returns me the default index page.

But localhost/DBConnect.php doesn't work (should connect to MongoDB)

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "MongoDB\Driver\Manager" not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/XProject/SOURCE/Server/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php:126 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/XProject/SOURCE/Server/DBConnect.php(8): MongoDB\Client->__construct('mongodb://local...') #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/XProject/SOURCE/Server/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php on line 126
```

PHP Version 8.2.0.

```
% php --ri mongodb | grep version
MongoDB extension version => 1.15.1
libbson bundled version => 1.23.2
libmongoc bundled version => 1.23.2
libmongocrypt bundled version => 1.5.2
crypt_shared library version => unknown
```

```
% pecl list-files mongodb | grep mongodb.so
src  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.15/pecl/20210902/mongodb.so
```

So I've set this in the project dir in the php.ini:

```
extension="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.15/pecl/20210902/mongodb.so"
```

Does anyone have a recommendation for me?

Comment: Did you check whether the mongodb extension is also available in the PHP configuration for Apache?

Comment: You mean in the phpinfo? No, its not listed there.

Comment: Then the problem is pretty obvious: you haven't enabled the extension properly

Comment: That would be my guess too. But what can I do to fix this? As pasted above it does find the MongoDB extension version, Mongo is running in a Docker container (Using MongoDB: 6.0.4) at mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ (console). I've edited the php.ini aswell

Comment: Why not enable the extension properly? I would assume that there are multiple php.ini files on your system. Check `phpinfo()` about the one that is used for your server process and modify it

Comment: I just checked it again. The right phpinfo was already modified (extension as above).

Comment: So, you've edited the php.ini that is shown in the phpinfo, but your extension isn't shown? Did you reload the server?

Comment: Yes, the extension isn't shown. Server is of course reloaded.

Comment: If the extension is not shown in phpinfo, the extension is not yet enabled properly, as I've mentioned earlier

Comment: Yes, and what can I try to fix this?